# Find the equations of the orbits of the following system:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the equations of the orbits of the following system:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = y^2$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{-2}{3}x$

I tried taking the derivative of the second equation with respect to t and obtaining:
$y '' = \frac{2}{3}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{2}{3}(y^2)$, but once I got here I plugged it into wolfram and got a solution containing a "Weierstrass elliptic function" which seems beyond the scope of the course (I've never seen these before.) I'm not sure how else I would do this.

Comment: "Orbit" here means just the trajectories, there is no closedness or periodicity involved? So $C=x^2+y^3$ would work as equation for the orbits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
dx = y^2dt \\
dy = \frac{-2}{3}x\;dt
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad 
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{-2x}{3y^2}$$
$$3y^2dy=-2x\;dx$$
$$y^3=-x^2+c$$
$$\text{The trajectory is :}\quad y^3+x^2=c$$
$$y(x)=\left(c-x^2\right)^{1/3}$$
NOTE :

If you want the time $t$ as a function of the position on the trajectory, solve $\frac{dx}{dt}=\left(c-x^2\right)^{2/3}$ which is separable. The integration involves a special function.